# Change class of an element with a radio button in a modal (Angular UI-Bootstrap: Retrieving values from a modal dialog window)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use a modal dialog and radio buttons to change the class of an element. The classes are theme-1, theme-2 and theme-3. I tried it with the directive ng-class, but this was not possible, because I need to provide an equal ng-model for the radio buttons.

With {{theme}} **in** the modal dialog, I get the value of the buttons. Outside the modal dialog, it do not work.

I can change the class even after closing the dialogue. But how can I do this in my ModalInstanceCtrl? 
Do you have any tip?

**HTML**

```
<h1 ng-model="theme">The new class: {{theme}}</h1>
```

**Angular UI Modal Dialog**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="NewInvoiceCtrl">                         
    <div class="btn-group btn-theme">
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-theme-label"  ng-model="theme" btn-radio='"theme-1"'>Light</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-theme-label"  ng-model="theme" btn-radio='"theme-2"'>Dark</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-theme-label"  ng-model="theme" btn-radio='"theme-3"'>Grey</label>
        {{theme}}
    </div>
   </form>
```

**JS**

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
// Change Design
    $scope.selectDesign = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');           


    };
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With {{theme}} in the modal dialog, I get the value of the buttons.
>   Outside the modal dialog, it do not work.

In the main window, you can get what was selected in the dialog window like this:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- For html5 (default is UTF-8) -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <!-- For Bootstrap -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- For Bootstrap -->

  <title>Test</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap3 -->
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- app.css -->
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MainWindowCtrl">
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open modal dialog window</button>
  <div ng-show="main.theme">Selection from the modal dialog was: {{main.theme}}</div>
</div>

<!-- Angular 1.3.2 -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular UI-Bootstrap -->
<script src="angular-ui-bootstrap-0.12.js"></script>

<!-- app.js -->
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainWindowCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {

  $scope.open = function() {

    var dialogWindow = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'DialogWindowCtrl',
    });

    dialogWindow.result.then(function(selectedTheme) {
      $scope.main = {
        theme: selectedTheme
      };
    });

  };

}]);

app.controller('DialogWindowCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',  function($scope, $modalInstance) {

  var dialogWindow = $modalInstance;
  //Set default value... 
  //ng-clicks in the dialog window change this value:
  $scope.dialog = {
    theme: 'theme1'
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    dialogWindow.close($scope.dialog.theme);  //***PASS DATA TO MAIN WINDOW**** 
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    dialogWindow.dismiss('cancel');
  };

}]);
```

#### Retrieve two values from a modal dialog:

(Also set a default active button, and activate the clicked button.)

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- For html5 (default is UTF-8) -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <!-- For Bootstrap -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- For Bootstrap -->

  <title>Test</title>

  <!--Bootstrap3 -->
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- app.css -->
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MainWindowCtrl">
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open modal dialog window</button>
  <div ng-show="main_data.theme">Theme from the modal dialog was: {{main_data.theme}}</div>
  <div ng-show="main_data.border">Border from the modal dialog was: {{main_data.border}}</div>
</div>

<!-- Angular 1.3.2 -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular UI-Bootstrap 0.12 -->
<script src="angular-ui-bootstrap-0.12.js"></script>

<!-- app.js -->
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainWindowCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {

  $scope.open = function() {

    $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'DialogWindowCtrl',
    })

    .result.then(function(dialog_data) {
      $scope.main_data = dialog_data;
      //equivalent to: $scope.main_data = {theme: 'selected theme', border: 'selected border'}
    });

  };

}]);

app.controller('DialogWindowCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',  function($scope, $modalInstance) {

  var dialogWindow = $modalInstance;

  $scope.dialog_data = {
    theme: 'theme1',
    border: 'solid'
  };

  $scope.setTheme = function(theme) {
    $scope.dialog_data.theme = theme;
  }

  $scope.ifThemeIs = function(theme) {
    return $scope.dialog_data.theme === theme;
  }

  $scope.setBorder = function(border) {
    $scope.dialog_data.border = border;
  }

  $scope.ifBorderIs = function(border) {
    return $scope.dialog_data.border === border;
  }

  $scope.ok = function () {
    dialogWindow.close($scope.dialog_data);  //***PASS DATA TO MAIN WINDOW***
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    dialogWindow.dismiss('cancel');
  };

}]);
```

myModalContent.html:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
  <h4>Theme:</h4>
  <div class="btn-group btn-theme">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-theme-label" 
           ng-click="setTheme('theme1')"
           ng-class="{active: ifThemeIs('theme1')}">Light</button> 
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-theme-label"
           ng-click="setTheme('theme2')"
           ng-class="{active: ifThemeIs('theme2')}">Dark</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-theme-label" 
           ng-click="setTheme('theme3')"
           ng-class="{active: ifThemeIs('theme3')}">Grey</button>
  </div>
  <div>Current theme choice: {{dialog_data.theme}}</div>

  <h4>Border:</h4>
  <div class="btn-group btn-theme">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-theme-label" 
           ng-click="setBorder('solid')"
           ng-class="{active: ifBorderIs('solid')}">Solid</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-theme-label" 
           ng-click="setBorder('dashed')"
           ng-class="{active: ifBorderIs('dashed')}">Dashed</button>
  </div>
  <div>Current border choice: {{dialog_data.border}}</div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @ 7stud, works like a charm! Thank you so much. I´ve learned the modal has also its own controller right?

Comment: @mm1975, Yes.  I edited my post and changed some of the variable names around to make it clearer what is going on, but briefly: 1) You use ng-click to set the value of a variable on the dialog's $scope. 2) When the dialog's OK button is clicked, the value of the variable is passed to the dialog's close() function.  The value is then retrieved in the other controller using the .result property for the dialog.  The value is then attached to another $scope object, whereupon the value can be retrieved on your main html page.

Comment: Thank you! One more question: I´ve tried to add one more selection in the dialog, called 'border'. How do get the result in the modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedTheme) {..}. I´ve tried to do this with (selectedTheme, selectedBorder) but it doesn´t work. Thanks

Comment: @mm1975, Instead of passing just the single value `$scope.dialog.theme` to `$modalInstance.close()`, you can pass the whole object, e.g. `$modalInstance.close($scope.dialog)`. Then in the dialog window, you can use ng-click to set as many key/value pairs on `$scope.dialog` as you want. I'll post an example, which also highlights the button that was clicked.